# How plot points based on categorical variable in plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I am using Plotly for visualization. I want to make plot, and give the points colors based on categorical variable.

```
    fig = go.Figure()
   
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.Predicted, y=df.Predicted,colors='Category',mode='markers',
                        
                        ))
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.Predicted, y=df.real ,   colors='Category'         
                      ))
    fig.show()
```

where Category is column in my dataframe. How can I do this kind of graph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- you have implied a data frame structure which I have simulated
- it's simpler to use **Plotly Express** higher level API that **graph objects**
- have used to calls to `px.scatter()` to generate traces defined in your question.  Plus have renamed traces in second call to ensure legend is clear and made them lines

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Predicted": np.sort(np.random.uniform(3, 15, 100)),
        "real": np.sort(np.random.uniform(3, 15, 100)),
        "Category": np.random.choice(list("ABCD"), 100),
    }
)

px.scatter(df, x="Predicted", y="Predicted", color="Category").add_traces(
    px.line(df, x="Predicted", y="real", color="Category")
    .for_each_trace(
        lambda t: t.update(name="real " + t.name)
    )  # make it clear in legend this is second set of traces
    .data
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have to use go.Figure() object, because I want to have line and scatter plot simulatneusly.

Comment: have updated answer, still uses **px** and generates lines and scatter.  Key is understanding figure / trace concepts rather than directly switch to **go**

Comment: @RobRaymond We need a solution not confusions. As per my experience, I firstly used `plotly.express` to face less complexity but when it comes to advance development, I had to go back to `graph_objects`. Plotly should not have created `plotly.express`.